# Loading PostCSS Plugin failed: Cannot find module 'fast-glob'

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css, astrojs

I was trying Astro build for the very first time. I follow the documentation and create an Astro app with `npm create astro@latest` and then `npm install` but when trying to run a server with `npm run dev` I am getting this error: **Loading PostCSS Plugin failed: Cannot find module 'fast-glob'**

I am not even using or configure tailwind CSS then why I am getting error related to it on a freshly setup Astro app

**Whole error log:**

01:16:23 pm [astro] Unable to load C:\Users\folder-path...\dangerous-disk\astro.config.mjs
error   Loading PostCSS Plugin failed: Cannot find module 'fast-glob'
Require stack:

- C:\Users\sahilp\Desktop\project\node_modules\tailwindcss\lib\lib\setupTrackingContext.js
- C:\Users\sahilp\Desktop\project\node_modules\tailwindcss\lib\index.js
- C:\Users\sahilp\Desktop\project\postcss.config.js
  (@C:\Users\sahilp\Desktop\project\postcss.config.js)
  Error: Loading PostCSS Plugin failed: Cannot find module 'fast-glob'
- C:\Users\sahilp\Desktop\project\node_modules\tailwindcss\lib\lib\setupTrackingContext.js
- C:\Users\sahilp\Desktop\project\node_modules\tailwindcss\lib\index.js
- C:\Users\sahilp\Desktop\project\postcss.config.js
  (@C:\Users\sahilp\Desktop\project\postcss.config.js)
  at load (C:\Users\folder-path...\dangerous-disk\node_modules\postcss-load-config\src\plugins.js:28:11)
  at C:\Users\folder-path...\dangerous-disk\node_modules\postcss-load-config\src\plugins.js:53:16